# How to create custom icon using clickonce

Tags: c#, asp.net, clickonce

I have created windows application and deploy using clickonce.

I do no know how to change icon created after installing application on machine.

I want change all of icons generated on desktop, startmenu and Add/Remove progrmas.

Comment: first post what you have done upto now.where you find problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to

- add the icons to the project
- update the icon selected everywhere you
  want the change to be
- re-deploy.

Answer (score 1):

IN visual Studio do the following

- Right Click The Project (not solution) -> Select Properties -> Default Icon -> Select a    Image

The image must be in .ico format, you can do this by using a tool such as this

http://www.icoconverter.com/